# error in delete method in class for visual studio

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

Sql stored proc

```
create procedure sp_deletelogin
    @Username varchar

as

delete login_user
where Username = @Username
```

code for delete method in class

```
 public static void Delete1(login_user table)
 {
     db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
     db.sp_deletelogin(table.Username);
 }
```

the error is this

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'WindowsFormsApplication2.DataClasses1DataContext.sp.deletelogin(char?)'
>   has some invalid arguments
>
> Argument '1': cannot convert from 'string' to 'char?'

Comment: Microsoft [advise not to use the sp prefix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115(v=vs.100).aspx) as it stands for "special" and not "stored procedure".

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a value to varchar - if you don't it will only look at the first letter. Try VarChar(50)

```
@Username varchar
```

will read as char, while

```
@Username varchar(50)
```

will read as string

Comment: Do you mean "length" rather than "value"?

Comment: Seeing how length is a value and must be a value, then yes - I suppose I do.

Comment: I think sp_deletelogin function has been designed to take character like sp_deletelogin (char s) not for string sp_deletelogin (string s).So rewrite the function for string instead of char